# PayPal REST API - subscriptions

Tags: paypal

I am using .NET SDK for PayPal and I want to use REST API (Agreements API)  in my application. My app was tested with sandbox credentials and worked fine but does not work with live credentials. I got 401 HTTP code response when it comes to creating a Plan. I am a non-U. S. developer. Is there any possibility to use Agreements API outside US or should I move to NVP/SOAP APIs?

Comment: Are you trying to use direct credit cards to setup the agreements, or are you doing it with PayPal wallet / login?

Comment: I am not using direct credit cards.

Comment: I am not using direct credit cards. I am able to create PayPal ApiContext with live credentials, but then Plan.Create() mtehod throws exception with message unauthorized.